# Find the length of the common chord between two circles

Tags: conic-sections

What is the length of the common chord between two circles whose equations are $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2-6x+2=0$

I have looked at similar problems elsewhere online but I keep getting different answers that do not seem correct. Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Where do they intersect?

Comment: Subtract one equation from the other to get a straight line. (called radical axis). Plug in x or y taking from this straight line into any one of the two circles and solve the quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

From the system we get $4-6x+2=0$ or $x=1$,

which gives two coommon points $A(1,\sqrt3)$,$B(1,-\sqrt3)$ and the answer: $2\sqrt3$.